# How to direct CXF-based build, to auto-generate namespace for xmlbeans derived from XSD having no targetNamespace?

Tags: xml, xsd, cxf, xml-namespaces, xmlbeans

I am maintaining a legacy CXF-based system that used to have all XSDs explicitly contain `targetNamespace="http://projname.sourceforge.net/topproj/subproj/XSDversion"`.

That worked well for the maven-based build to auto-generate xmlbeans with properly nested directories based on package name derived from the namespace:

[image]

But when I updated the XSDs (dictated by an external source, **not in my organization's control**), they came without a `targetNamespace` (everything else is fine, including `elementFormDefault="qualified"`) and so the build environment did not produce a package name and directory hierarchy:

[image]

What do I need to change in my project setup to work properly with those new XSDs?

Do I need to "hack" those XSDs to contain a dummy/desired `targetNamespace`?

Or is there a more correct way of handling this, not relying on a `targetNamespace` attribute to be present?